# Get GPS source information in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, geolocation, gps

I have an Angular 2 application where I need to retrieve the GPS position of the device. I know that I can use window.geolocation.watchposition() to be updated about the GPS position, but I have to differentiate the information with respect to the source that has generated the position.

Is there a way to understand if the retrieved information gas been generated bu: hardware GPS, web, and so on. With the highaccuracy option set to true, if I understand correctly, I can say that I would prefer the hardware information, but what I need is to know for each coordinates obtained, who gave me that.

Is it possible directly from JavaScript insider the browser?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not in the browser - no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the HTML5 Geolocation API work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496085/how-does-the-html5-geolocation-api-work)

Answer (score 0):

As a callback to your `success` handler, you get a `Position` object only. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Position, it just contains the coordinates and a timestamp. There is no way to understand which location provider the position came from.